# How can I develop my own web app running on Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

I had experience of building normal web apps for desktop and mobile before, and want to create my own video web app (similar to Youtube TV) on cross platforms, e.g. Smart TVs, game consoles.

I heard of Cobalt recently and all I know so far is a lightweight browser that we could run web applications using a subset of HTML/CSS/JS on it.

I also read the documentation of Cobalt (https://cobalt.dev/) but I'm still confused about it. It seems that Cobalt could be built only on Linux or Raspberry Pi. Could anyone provide some tutorial or explanation about how the development process looks like?

Comment: Stack Overflow policy requires questions to contain code. For general discussion, please use cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com.

Comment: Also, please clarify more precisely the nature of your issues with Cobalt. Are you expecting support for a particular platform? Are you looking for a documentation about feature set? Are you trying to run Cobalt locally and don't know how to?

Comment: Right. Please join https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cobalt-dev and send an email to cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com for this kind of questions. Feel free to use this Stackoverflow when you have a technical questions along with the code.

Comment: @mmotorny No, questions do not have to contain code, if code isn't relevant.  Questions just need to be reasonably scoped, with relevant information, in such a way to be answerable.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for clarifying, Brad! I swear I saw this policy about code somewhere but can't find it anymore.

Comment: @mmotorny Yeah, no problem.  For what it's worth, showing code is the best (only?) way to have a reasonable scoped answerable question for ~99% of situations, which is why it's one of the close-vote options.  But, I think a question like this one is acceptable.  Others may disagree.  :-)

Comment: @mmotorny Thanks for pointing it out. I'll consider more next time.

Comment: @chung1350 Did you post a question on cobalt-dev about this?

Comment: @Sparkleholic not sure if it was OP but this is a very similar question over there: https://groups.google.com/g/cobalt-dev/c/cKRLN5ruMAc/m/oJF3AMrnAAAJ

Answer (score 0):

After you compiled and built your `cobalt` binary on e.g. Linux using [this guide](https://cobalt.dev/development/setup-linux.html). You can then run Cobalt using the `--url` flag:

```
./cobalt --url="<MY_WEBAPP_URL>"
```

source: https://groups.google.com/g/cobalt-dev/c/cKRLN5ruMAc/m/oJF3AMrnAAAJ